# Nginx proxy redirect path to docker service

Tags: docker, nginx, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I'm trying to redirect traffic from app.domain.com/test path to my `backend` service. I'm using `jwilder/nginx-proxy` and I'm trying to achive this using env VIRTUAL_PATH, but its not working properly.

I have a path /api in my backend service and when I'm sending request to this like: app.domain.com/test/api, I've got 404 error. Without VIRTUAL_HOST env its working great on app.domain.com/api. What is wrong whit my docker compose file?

```
version: '2'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

  backend:
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=app.domain.com
      - VIRTUAL_PATH=/test
```

Thanks.